# Use boostrap modal via javascript in angular (.ts) without NgbModule?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to customise and component that have an interaction with UI.
I already change all necessary files, but in my new component I am confuse how to import so the bootstrap class are recognized in typescript. I just migrate from javascript to typescript, so this is what happen.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-modal',
  templateUrl: './modal.component.html'
})
export class ModalComponent implements OnInit {
  modal: any;
  shown: false;
  constructor() {
    this.modal= new bootstrap.modal('#id', {
      keyboard: true
    });
    this.shown= false;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('modal on init');
  }

  onClick(): void {

  }
}
```

Comment: Which class do you want to be recognized? Or do you want to know how to instantiate the `bootstrap` variable? Are you using plain bootstrap or ng-bootstrap?

Comment: plain bootstrap, instanciate bootstrap component rn, but i if you can guide me how to use other lib in angular is great, i.e d3js and moment.

Comment: I strongly suggest you to use angular modules instead of plain js libraries, since you get features like tree shakability and will be able to inject the required services directly in you components. E.g. in your case it would be better to use https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home where you can inject the `bootstrap` service in your component (as shown here: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples). If you want to I can also provide the example in an answer, if that is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you, but this is my headfirst angular. I need to practice to create a component, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some quick guide on how to open up a ng-bootstrap modal in you application:

1. Add `ng-bootstrap` to your angular application by running `ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap`.
2. Add `NgbModalModule` to the imports array of your `app.module.ts`.
3. Create a new component which contains the content of your modal (by running `ng g c your/component/path/componentName`
4. Pass the modal service of ng-bootstrap to the component where you want to open the modal by injecting it in your constructor: `constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) {}`
5. In your onClick function (or whereever you want to actually open the modal), include the following code: `this.modalService.open(ComponentName);`